# How to change value of global variable using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm new to AngularJS and charts. I defined x and y value inside a ajax call. However, I found out only when $scope.categories and $scope.dataset(these are x and y values) defined outside of the ajax call, the plot can be displayed. That is to say, these variables can only be defined at the place of the explanation in code snippet below.
However, I don't know how to change their values as global variable. I guess it can be done using scope but I don't know how...

Here is part of my code:

```js
app.controller("MyController", function($scope,$http){
    var newArray=[];
    var vArray=[];
    $http.get("model/select.php").success(function(data){

        /*Define newArray and vArray's value as what read from database 
        using php here*/
        $scope.categories = [{"category":newArray}]
        $scope.dataset = [{"data":vArray}]


    }).error(function(){
        alert("An unexpected error occurred!");
    });
 /*$scope.attr, $scope.categories, $scope.dataset can be only defined here, out side of $http() and inside controller*/

});
```

Comment: It is very confusing. what are you trying to achieve? what is it that you want to happen?

Comment: I want to make plot using angularjs with dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$rootScope` ? Look into the Angular JS documentation for $rootScope, you can change values in other controllers using it.

Comment: There is only one controller. But the value is only affected inside $http.get function. I want to know how to maintain it outside this function but still inside this controller.